# What's with the 'in' keyword?

Tags: haskell, syntax

In Haskell, why do you not use 'in' with 'let' inside of a do-block, but you must otherwise?

For example, in the somewhat contrived examples below:

```
afunc :: Int -> Int
afunc a = 
       let x = 9 in
       a * x

amfunc :: IO Int -> IO Int
amfunc a = do
       let x = 9
       a' <- a
       return (a' * x)
```

It's an easy enough rule to remember, but I just don't understand the reason for it.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged it [haskell] but, I just edited the text to make it clear.

Comment: There's no deep reason, it's just the way it is.

Comment: It's convenient, because if you have multiple `let`s in a do-block, with an `in`, you'd need a `do` after each `in` (if there's more than one statement following).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are providing expressions to define both `afunc` and `amfunc`. Let-expressions and do-blocks are both expressions. However, while a let-expression introduces a new binding that scopes around the expression given after the 'in' keyword, a do-block isn't made of expressions: it is a sequence of *statements*. There are three forms of statements in a do-block:

1. a computation whose result is bound to some variable `x`, as in

   ```
   x <- getChar
   ```
2. a computation whose result is ignored, as in

   ```
   putStrLn "hello"
   ```
3. A let-statement, as in

   ```
   let x = 3 + 5
   ```

A let-statement introduces a new binding, just as let-expressions do. The scope of this new binding extends over all the remaining statements in the do-block.

In short, what comes after the 'in' in a let-expression is an expression, whereas what comes after a let expression is a sequence of statements. I can of course express a computation of a particular statement using a let-expression, but then the scope of the binding would not extend beyond that statement to statements that follow. Consider:

```
do putStrLn "hello"
   let x = 3 + 5 in putStrLn "eight"
   putStrLn (show x)
```

The above code causes the following error message in GHC:

```
Not in scope: `x'
```

whereas

```
do putStrLn "hello"
   let x = 3 + 5
   putStrLn "eight"
   putStrLn (show x)
```

works fine.

Answer (score 9):

You can indeed use `let .. in` in do-notation. In fact, according to the Haskell Report, the following

> do{let decls; stmts}

desugars into

> let decls in do {stmts}

I imagine that it is useful because you might otherwise have to have some deep indentation or delimiting of the "in"-block, going from your in .. to the very end of the do-block.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that Haskell `do` blocks are funny.  Haskell is an expression-based language—except in `do` blocks, because the point of `do` blocks is to provide for a "statement" syntax of sorts.  Most "statements" are just expressions of type `Monad m => m a`, but there are two syntaxes that don't correspond to anything else in the language:

1. Binding the result of an action with `<-`: `x <- action` is a "statement" but not an expression.  This syntax requires `x :: a` and `action :: Monad m => m a`.
2. The `in`-less variant of `let`, which is like an assignment statement (but for pure code on the right hand side).  In `let x = expr`, it must be the case that `x :: a` and `expr :: a`.

Note that just like uses of `<-` can be desugared (in that case, into `>>=` and lambda), the `in`-less `let` can always be desugared into the regular `let ... in ...`:

```
do { let x = blah; ... }
    => let x = blah in do { ... }
```