# Haskell syntax error?

Tags: haskell

I cant compile this part of code:

```
game a = let 
             gameBoard ++ a
             black = test a colors
             white = (test2 a colors) - black
             createScore black white
         in 
             merge gameBoard score
```

geting: Syntax error in declaration (unexpected `}', possibly due to bad layout)

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't see a `}` anywhere...

Comment: What it is doing `gameBoard ++ a`??

Comment: @Himanshu gameBoard and a are lists.

Comment: This might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674892/whats-with-the-in-keyword

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `}` shows up unexpectedly (and not very newbie-friendly) in error messages because indentation blocks in Haskell are nominally syntactic sugar for explicit `{;}`s. It really means that an indentation block ended before it was complete.

Answer (score 1):

The `in` is part of the same `let` statement, so has to be on the same line or further indented, for example

```
game a = let 
             gameBoard ++ a
             black = test a colors
             white = (test2 a colors) - black
             createScore black white
               in 
                 merge gameBoard score
```

Haskell's layout rule for syntax is roughly that if it's further in it's the same line, if it's lined up it's a new line within a block, and if it's outdented it's the end of a block, which is why your `in` generated a close brace.